# Convert char input to user defined table type and call one stored procedure from other stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

In first stored procedure testList is user defined table type

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [working].[test1] (@input1 int, @input2 testList READONLY) AS
BEGIN

// do some working

END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [working].[test2] (@input3 int, @input4 char) AS
BEGIN

// How can i convert char input4 to user defined table input testList 
// I want to do that conversion because ,here i want to call stored procedure test1

EXEC [working].[test1] @input1 = @input3 , @input2 = CAST(@input4 AS testList);

// is this correct way to call ?

END
GO
```

Comment: @Tim Zimmermann : Thanks for the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [working].[test2] 
   @input3 int, 
   @input4 CHAR(N)
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Declare a table variable of testList type

DECLARE @Table_Var AS testList;

--  Populate the table variable with value passed to @input4  

INSERT INTO @Table_Var (ColumnName)
VALUES (@input4)


-- Now pass this table variable to your procedure 

EXEC [working].[test1] @input1 = @input3 
                     , @input2 = @Table_Var

END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But what do you mean by Table variable schema ?

Comment: sorry this is something you would define when creating the type itself. The only issue you have with your current approach is that you cannot cast or convert variable `@input4` to your user defined data type.

Comment: You will need to declare a variable of that user defined table type and then populate it with values passed to `@input4` variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a quick reply. I will try and let you know if it works for me :)